# How to apply gradle to an existing multiple java project?

Tags: java, gradle

I would like to know how gradle build can be applied on existing multiple java project which doesn't have expected directory structure - src/main/java etc?

Thank you in advance,
mismas

Comment: Make your project public and ask for pull request :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Especially this part: 23.4.1. Changing the project layout